# Ajax readystatechange strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello stackoverflow commmunity, i have STRANGE issue. 
I use ajax to upload file to server. Here is the code:

```html
 // request
 request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event){
  if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
   if (request.responseText=="upload_successful"){
    alert("Thank you for sharing past test.");
    $(".form").hide();
    $(".overlay").hide();
   }
  }
  else {
   alert("Sorry, there was a problems adding your test.");
   console.log("This server replied with HTTP status "+this.status);
  }
 });
```

Everything works fine on my localhost, but on the real sever my alert message ("Sorry, there was a problem etc..") appears (two or three times) after that ("Thank you for sharing...") alert appears, and my file is uploaded to server and added to database too. 
So why does it goes two or three times to ELSE and then jumps to IF part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AJAX request goes through a number of intermediate states before it's finished. Each of these state changes triggers the `onreadystatechange` handler. Those other states aren't errors, they're just temporary conditions before the request is completed.

An error is indicated by the `status` property. If you want to report an error, it should be something like:

```
if (this.readyState == 4) { // request is completed
    if (this.status == 200 && this.responseText=="upload_successful") { // request was successful
        alert("Thank you for sharing past test.");
        $(".form").hide();
        $(".overlay").hide();
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, there was a problems adding your test.");
        console.log("This server replied with HTTP status "+this.status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem by just moving alert() to the first IF statements, so user doesnt see it any more in case if file is uploaded. But i am still interested in knowing why do we jump several time to the ELSE.

Comment: XHR goes through lots of intermediate states before getting to state 4.